# Count Total Images attach to post and print result in title - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show total number of images in my post title. for ex: "my post is This car for sale ( 4 images)"  if this is the title i want to print 4 in my title before images. i try this code yet but it show 0. i dont know why. so can you please help me in this. Please note: im new to php and wordpress.

```
$count = count( $attachments );
$specific = array();
$i = 1;

foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    $specific[$attachment->ID] = $i;
    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: In which context do you have this code? How do you populate `$attachments`? Why aren't you just using `$count`? Why are you creating an array with `id => number`? How are you outputting the result? Without context, this code tells us nothing.

Comment: Down Vote is not providing answer or help anyway. if you need any more information you can ask and i will try my best to provide, this is on my live site so sometime it take time. anyways thanks for help  ..

Comment: 1. I asked 20 minutes ago with any response. 2. Before posting, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you don't, you risk getting down votes since the question will be considered as a low quality question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry for delay as also searching on net i not know that you are asking any thing, when i again visit this site i see an answer also their and i try that first as i got error on live site so invest time to solve this first. anyways sorry if you get problem anyway .

Comment: No worries. I do recommend you to read the guidelines properly before posting next time though. In general, the better the question is, the better the answers will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below solution

for this, you need to pass your post id

```
<?php
$getAttachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID ) );
$count = count( $getAttachments );
echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: That would give you _everything_ that has the post as parent, like sub-posts etc, not just attachments. We also don't know how the OP currently is populating the `$attachment`-variable.

Comment: @Mohsin Marui  i got error if i use this code with  title code <?php 
$getAttachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID ) );
$count = count( $getAttachments );
  
  the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">','.$count.''</h1>' ); ?>

Comment: @deccc - _"I got error"_ isn't that informative. What error do you get? Also, you should answer the questions in the comment under your question. It helps if you give us some proper information.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''</h1>'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in  /....//template-parts/content-single.php on line 15

Comment: issue with concatenation please use this the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">',.$count.'</h1>' );

Comment: @MagnusEriksson hope eror code help you to solve this

Comment: @mohsin got this new error after try  new code   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'

Comment: Just do: `the_title('<h1 class="entry-title">',  " $count</h1>");` (this will actually give you a space between the title and the number as well).

Comment: `the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">',$count.'</h1>' ); `please try this one.